# Query to determine if Backup Exec is taking backups

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

Does anyone know any tactics to determine if backup exec is taking backup? We do not have access to the program to determine if it is in charge but are receiving alerts for failed backups. If you run the `select * from dbo.backupmediaset` for System databases it normally returns what software is being used, however Backup Exec will still return SQL Server.

The backupmediaset tactic also does not work for any user databases as it is only included in the msdb System DB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dbo.backupset instead of dbo.backupmediaset?

```
SELECT TOP 20 database_name,
              type,
              backup_start_date, 
              backup_finish_date,
              compressed_backup_size,
              backup_size
FROM   msdb.dbo.backupset
ORDER  BY backup_set_id DESC;
```

This is what I use, the dbo.backupset table should have a history of all backups ever run on your SQL server, unless someone ins manually purging that table, which is often times overlooked.

More details at my blog:
http://stevestedman.com/2012/01/latest-backups/

I hope this helps.   Have a great day!